# llvm-ld: error: Cannot load file 'tree.o': Bitcode file 'tree.o' could not be loaded: Unknown bitstream version

Tags: llvm

I have encountered an error when trying to use llvm-ld to link bitcode files. The file "tree.o" is a LLVM bitcode file. When doing llvm-ld tree.o, there comes *llvm-ld: error: Cannot load file 'tree.o': Bitcode file 'tree.o' could not be loaded: Unknown bitstream version!*

What's wrong?

Comment: Which LLVM version are you using?

Answer (score 1):

The llvm-ld tool has been [removed from LLVM in 3.1](http://llvm.org/releases/3.1/docs/ReleaseNotes.html), which is quite an old version by now.

You should be using `llvm-link` to perform bitcode linking. However, note that the version of the tools should match the version of Clang or LLVM used to generate the bitcode files these tools operate on.